# Background Image Not Visible when not using live server

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, liveserver

## I'm using Vs code with live server extension But When I open the HTML file or on GitHub pages The out does not show the background image

Overall Every Style I applied is working,
but only the background image of the
`.left`
div inside
`.home`
section

---

> **I have tried using CSS instead of SCSS**

---

**I have this snippet**

*Snippet won't work*
*as the image is local and if I add external URL then It works*

```css
 .home .left {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: url("media/bgH.png") no-repeat center fixed;
    }
```

```html
<HTML>
 <head>
  </head>
 <body>  
    <section id="home" class="home">
          <div class="left">
            <div class="container">
  </body>
<HTML>
```

---

I tired swapping
`background: url("media/bgH.png") no-repeat center fixed`
for
`background: url("./../../media/bgH.png")`
and also to
`background: url("../../media/bgH.png")`

---

**This link is for the GitHub Page**

> maybe this link will help
> [HERE!](https://kushagra-aa.github.io/portfolio/)

---

**This The folder structure**
[HERE!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhMC5.png)

Comment: have you tried writing it as `... url("./media/bgH.png") ...`? the dot indicates current directory.

Comment: no this doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url is incorrect, try using:

```
  background: url("./media/bgH.png") no-repeat center fixed;
```

Comment: Try Adding code in code blocks please!

Answer (score 0):

pip3 install -r requirements.txt
pip3 install pyOpenSSL

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm not sure what you suggesting and why are you suggesting it, Kindly add some supporting information also :)